# $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e and $\int_\mathbb{R} f_n dm \rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f dm$ implies $\int_E f_n dm \rightarrow \int_E f dm$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative lebesgue  measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R}) $.
if $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e on $\mathbb{R}$ and 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_n dm \rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f dm \quad \text{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty $$
 prove that  $$\int_E f_n dm \rightarrow  \int_E f dm \quad \text{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty .$$  for all measurable subsets E

Here are a couple of ideas that I have.

$f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e on $\mathbb{R}$ implies

if we let $A:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|f_n (x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$. then $m(A)=0$

Let $\mathbb{R}=A\cup B$ where $B=\mathbb{R}\backslash A$

then  $E \subset \mathbb{R} = (E\cap A) \cup ( E\cap B)$

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n dm=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\big[\int_A f_n dm+\int_B f_n dm\big]=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_B f_n dm = \int_\mathbb{R} f_n dm$$
i.e since $m(A)=0$ , $\int_A f_n dm \overset{?}= 0$ $\forall n$

On the other hand 
$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_E f_n dm=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n \chi_E= lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n \chi_{(E\cap A) \cup ( E\cap B)}= lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\big[\int_\mathbb{R} f_n \chi_{(E\cap A) }dm+\int_\mathbb{R} f_n\chi_{(E\cap B)}dm\big]$$

But $(E\cap A) \subset A $ so $m((E\cap A))=0$ $\Rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f_n \chi_{(E\cap A)}=0$ $\quad$ Hence
$$=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n\chi_{(E\cap B)}$$

If a sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$, then every subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ converges to $a$ [is this correct correct?]
So $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n\chi_{(E\cap B)}=\int_\mathbb{R} f dm$$.

can someone Kindly verify or correct it, or produce a proof? Thank you.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212418/showing-int-e-f-lim-n-to-infty-int-e-f-n-for-all-measurable-e).

Comment: You should add, in the end of the statement of the theorem, "for all measurable subsets $E\subset R$".

Comment: okay, I just did. 
I understand your proof below. but does mine make  sense?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/678282/

Comment: No, your proof is not correct since $m(A)$ does **not** equal $0$.

Comment: Okay. But I believed that is the definition of convergence a. e. 
That is,  the set of points for which the condition does not hold has a measure of zero.

Comment: @J.Kyei that's right, but your definition for $A$ is not the same as the set of all $x$ for which $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma,

$$\int_{\Bbb R\setminus E} f\, dm \le \liminf\int_{\Bbb R\setminus E} f_n\,dm$$

or
$$\int_{\Bbb R} f\, dm - \int_E f\, dm \le \liminf \left(\int_{\Bbb R} f_n\, dm - \int_E f_n\, dm\right)$$

Using the condition $\int_{\Bbb R} f_n \, dm \to \int_{\Bbb R} f\, dm$, the inequality becomes

$$\int_{\Bbb R} f\, dm - \int_E f\, dm \le \int_{\Bbb R} f\, dm - \limsup \int_E f_n\, dm$$

Since $\int_{\Bbb R} f\, dm$ is finite, we deduce

$$\int_E f\, dm \ge \limsup \int_E f_n\, dm$$

On the other hand, Fatou's lemma also gives

$$\liminf \int_E f_n\, dm \ge \int_E f\, dm$$

Therefore $\int_E f_n\, dm \to \int_E f\, dm$.

Comment: How do we know that $\int_{\Bbb R\setminus E}f_n \ dm \to \int_{\Bbb R\setminus E}f \ dm$ so that we may apply Fatou's lemma?

Comment: @Addem it is assumed that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions converging pointwise a.e. to $f$. So Fatou's lemma may be applied to obtain $\int_{\Bbb R\setminus E} f\, dm \le \liminf\int_{\Bbb R\setminus E} f_n\ , dm$.