# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{A}f_{n}d\mu=\int_{A}fd\mu.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurables functions non-negatives such that  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X}f_{n}d\mu =\int_{X}fd\mu<+\infty. $$
> Prove that for all measurable set $E\subseteq X$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E}f_{n}d\mu=\int_{E}fd\mu.$$

**My approach:** Let $E\subseteq X$ measurable set, so we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E}f_{n}d\mu\overbrace{=}^{definition}\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X} f_{n}\cdot \chi_{E}d\mu\overbrace{=}^{de: \chi_{E}}\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E}f_{n}d\mu\overbrace{=}^{hypothesis?}\int_{E}fd\mu $$

---

*Is my proof correct?*
*I don't know how can I use the hypothesis $f_{n}\overset{a.e.x}{\to}f$*
*How can I conclude in my prove?*

Comment: I can't use the dominate convergence theorem.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Is my prove correct? How can I prove this statement?

Comment: No, your proof has the shape "$A=B=A=\text{answer}"$, I don't know why you return to the same expression $A$. If you can't use dct then you can follow the proof of dct

Comment: Uhm, by definition I know that $\int_{E}f_nd\mu=\int_{X}f_{n}\cdot \chi_{E}d\mu$. So, using the definition  of $\chi$, we have $\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu$?

Comment: Let me be more precise; your steps $"A=B=A"$ are logically correct, but not at all helpful. The remaining step "$=\text{answer}$"is the only important part, and remains unjustified

Comment: Can you write a hint with more details for my question? I don't know how to continue, because if I follow the proof of dct I need the hpothesis $f_{n}\leq f$ and I don't have that hypothesis. I need to contruction an auxiliar function?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. But the main tool is still Fatou's lemma. You do it once in the obvious direction $\int_E f = \int_E \liminf_n f_n \le  \liminf_n \int_E f_n$ but then also $\int_{X\setminus E} \liminf_n f_n \le \liminf_n \int_{X\setminus E} f_n$, after a few lines it should be clear

Comment: Dominated Convergence Theorem is applicable. Of course, we do not have $|f_n|\leq |f|$. Dominated Convergence Theorem is used in a tricky way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e and $\int_\mathbb{R} f_n dm \rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f dm$ implies $\int_E f_n dm \rightarrow \int_E f dm$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076959/f-n-rightarrow-f-a-e-and-int-mathbbr-f-n-dm-rightarrow-int-mathbbr)

Comment: A stronger and very often used result is Scheffés Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Comment: Above result is proved easily by applying Fatou's Lemma to $|f|+|f_n|-|f-f_n|$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy That is, in my proof, I have actually proved Scheffes Lemma.

Comment: Thank so much! I could understand the prove.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Since OP doesn't want to use DCT I suggested  a proof using Fatou' lemma. Besides I feel that you are making things a bit more complicated than what is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $(f_{n})$ be a
sequence of real-valued integrable functions defined on $X$. Let
$f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Suppose that
$f_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e., then $\lim_{n}\left(||f_{n}||-||f||-||f_{n}-f||\right)=0$,
where $||f||=\int|f|d\mu$ etc...

We go to prove the above assertion. Observe that $|f_{n}-f|\leq|f_{n}|+|f|$,
so $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\geq-2|f|.$ On the other hand, $|f_{n}|\leq|f_{n}-f|+|f|$
and hence $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\leq0\leq2|f|$. Combining, we have
$\Biggl||f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\Biggr|\leq2|f|$. Clearly, $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\rightarrow0$
a.e.. By Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that $\int\left(|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\right)d\mu\rightarrow 0$.
That is, $||f_{n}||-||f||-||f_{n}-f||\rightarrow0$.

Go back to our question. Since $f_{n}$ and $f$ are non-negative,
$||f_{n}||=\int f_{n}$ and $||f||=\int f$. It is given that $||f_{n}||\rightarrow||f||$.
Therefore, $||f_{n}-f||=\left(||f_{n}||-||f||\right)-\left(||f_{n}||-||f||-||f_{n}-f||\right)\rightarrow0$.
Finally, if $E\subseteq X$ is measurable, we have $\int_{E}|f_{n}-f|\leq||f_{n}-f||\rightarrow0$.
Therefore $\int_{E}f_{n}\rightarrow\int_{E}f$.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, but how as I said in the comments I can't use the dominated convergence theorem. However, thank you for your answer. Regards.